# How to remove an Item from FirebaseListAdapter depending on a certain condition

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have created a chat application using firebase database as its backend.
I want to show all the users who currently signed up in my application to any user who launches the application except showing his or her name on the user's list.

I have used FirebaseListAdapter, a ListView and Single User layout.
Here is the source code. I am getting all the users in a separate thread.

I tried to overriding isEnabled method though it did not work.It only disables the list item which corresponds to user who is looking at the current users list.

```
private class LoadFriends extends Thread{

        ChatHomeActivity chatHomeActivity;
        int pos;
        public LoadFriends(ChatHomeActivity chatHomeActivity) {
            this.chatHomeActivity = chatHomeActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            final FirebaseListAdapter<UserDetailsClass> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<UserDetailsClass>(chatHomeActivity,UserDetailsClass.class,R.layout.friend_online,tempUserRef) {
//                @Override
//                protected void populateView(View v, User model, int position) {
//
//                    TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
//                    TextView online_offline = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
//                    String uID = model.getUniqueID();
//
//                    if(uID.equals(UserDetails.getString("UniqueID","ID"))){
//                        sender = model.getName();
//                        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                    }
//                    if(!uID.equals(UserDetails.getString("UniqueID","ID"))){
//                        t.setText(model.getName());
//                        int x= model.getOnline();
//
//                        if(x == 0){
//                            online_offline.setText(" ");
//                            online_offline.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//                        }
//                        if (x == 1){
//                            online_offline.setText("Online");
//                            online_offline.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
//                        }
//                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    }
//                }

                @Override
                protected void populateView(View v, UserDetailsClass model, int position) {

                    TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    TextView online_offline = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                    String uID = model.getUserID();

                    if(uID.equals(UserDetails.getString("UniqueID","ID"))){
                        sender = model.getName();
                        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        pos = position;
                        //isEnabled(position);
                        //v.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
                    }
                    if(!uID.equals(UserDetails.getString("UniqueID","ID"))){
                        t.setText(model.getName());
                        int x= model.getOnline_offline_status();

                        if(x == 0){
                            online_offline.setText(" ");
                            online_offline.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                        if (x == 1){
                            online_offline.setText("Online");
                            online_offline.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        }
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //areAllItemsEnabled();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position!= pos){
                        return true;
                    }
                    return super.isEnabled(position);
                }

                //                @Override
//                public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
//                    return true;
//                }

                @Override
                public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
                    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```